# Dudas con funciones recursivas

Tags: funciones, recursión

Tengo dudas con como determinar el resultado de estas funciones recursivas, no logro llegar al resultado correcto.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que lenguaje se supone que es???  dependiendo de eso b=0 puede ser una asignacion y no una expresion booleana

Comment: Tengo entendido que no es ninguno en especifico, sino un pseudo-codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La recursión la puedes analizar como una acumulación de resultados sucesivos, que **recursivamente** se van desarrollando entonces para analizar lo que sucede en ese algoritmo, matemáticamente esto se conoce como composición de funciones

Hagamos el ejemplo de como se ejecuta ese algoritmo cuando usas los argumentos 25, 6
en el primer código

- 25 > 6
- A(19, 6) + 1
- 19 > 6
- (A(13, 6) + 1) + 1  <+++++++++++++++++++ Aca A(19, 6) es igual a A(13, 6) + 1
- 13 > 6
- ((A(7, 6) + 1) + 1) + 1 <+++++++++++++++++++ Aca A(13, 6) es igual a A(7, 6) + 1
- 7 > 6
- (((A(1, 6) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1 <+++++++++++++++++++ Aca A(7, 6) es igual a A(1, 6) + 1
- 1 < 6
- (((0 + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1 <+++++++++++++++++++ Aca A(1, 6) es igual a 0

Tu resultado da entonces **4**

En la recursión siempre tienes que analizar dos cosas: La condición de parada y la condición cíclica o recursiva, la condición de parada es sencilla porque sabes que en ella no vuelves a hacer llamados recursivos, la condición recursiva es la que tienes que revisar y preguntarte ¿cómo cada llamado recursivo aporta al resultado final?